# multiple get request on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

Is it possible to integrate within a click event multiple get request? I am getting adress data from a database. As a second step I extracted the  coordinates and send them back to the server. I want to pass the points which are within a buffer to Javascript.

```
$("#ok").click( function(event) {


$.get(url + 'c=' + text, function(data) {

   result1 = data;


$.ajax({
   url: my_url,
   type: "POST",
   data: my_data
  });

 });

 $.get(url, function(data) {

    result2 = data;
    console.log("yes");

   });

  });
```

Comment: Yes you can, but every new request should be executed as a [`done` callback of the former.

Comment: The `$.get` and `$.ajax` methods are asynchronous. They are not firing the way you think they are.  And you have some scope issues; the variables set inside your callbacks aren't available in other callbacks unless you pass them in.

Comment: so what would you recommend me to use? cause with `$.get` I get adress data from my database and with `$.ajax` I send the long lat coordinates based on the adress back to the server

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`done`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/). When one request is ready and processed, let's execute the other using `done`. See below. Also I've hoisted the `x` and `y` up to make them available throughout the block.

```
$("#ok").click( function(event) {

     var text = $('#st').val();
     var x,y;
     $.get('localhost:5000/adress?' + 'c=' + text, function(data) {

          mydata2 = data; //JSON.parse is not needed

          for (var i = 0; i <mydata2.length; i++){
          y = mydata2[i][1];
          x = mydata2[i][0];

          l = L.marker([y, x]).addTo(map);
      }).done(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost:5000/long_lat',
            type: "POST",
            data: {"x": x, "y": y}
      }).done(function(){

          $.get('localhost:5000/long_lat', function(data) {

          mydata3 = (data);
          console.log("yes");

         });
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: There is an error with 400 BAD REQUEST on the second get request

Comment: at the end of my code I additionally  added `});` but there is still the bad request error message